# Save file uploads to Mongo DB using Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, express

Following [this tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/handle-file-uploads-in-express-node-js.html), I have managed to create a form with a `file` input that uploads files to a specified directory. That's dandy and all, but it doesn't save anything to a database and I don't have any reference to the files that were uploaded to display in a Jade template.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
// add new bulletin
exports.addbulletin = function(db) {
    return function(req, res) {

        var tmp_path = req.files.coverimage.path;
        // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
        var target_path = './public/uploads/' + req.files.coverimage.name;
        // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
        fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.coverimage.size + ' bytes');
            });
        });

        // Submit to the DB
        collection.insert(req.body, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("There was a problem adding the information to the database.");
            }
            else {
                res.location("index");
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        });

    }
};
```

The second part of that is inserting the `req.body` (the other form fields that aren't file inputs) to a Mongo database. I would like to just tack on `req.files` along with where it's inserting the `req.body`, but that doesn't work.

My confusion kind of lies with how Mongo works too, I think. I'm no database expert, but when you "upload" an image, should the actual image file go to the database, or should just a reference (like the image name and location of it in the app) get added?

So in summary, I just want to save the uploaded image (or a reference to it) to the Mongo database so that I can then reference it in a Jade template to be displayed to the user.

For what it's worth, here's the relevant parts of the form (using Jade for templating):

```
form.new-bulletin(name="addbulletin", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data", action="/addbulletin")
  input(type="file", name="coverimage")
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add that I'm using [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty)

```
multipart = require("connect-multiparty"),
multiparty = multipart();
app.post("/addbulletin", multiparty, routes.addbulletin(db));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so the tutorial you are following is using the example of taking the *temporary* file information from the upload, and **moving** that file to another location.

So as it stand, you have the `target_path` variable in your code which shows where to **find** the file on disk. So if you want to store a **reference**, there you have it, and future reads of your mongo document will have that path information so you could access the file again.

As you have said, you probably don't want to be passing in the whole `res.body` but just access properties of it like this and construct your own document in which to insert/update whatever. Information on accessing info on the `File` is in the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.files).

If you decide you want to put the *File Content* into your mongo document, then it is just a matter of reading the file content in. Here the core node documentation for [File System](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) operators may be of assistance to you. Particularly the [read](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) function.

From a MongoDB standpoint you can just add that content to any document field, it won't care and handles binary types. Provided that your size is under the 16MB BSON limitation.

Over that limit and maybe of interest to you, would be [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/). And for reference there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860005/storing-data-stream-from-post-request-in-gridfs-express-mongodb-node-js) on SO that may provide you with some insight on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you made an interesting point about using the `target_path` variable. I've since added like so `collection.insert((req.body, target_path), function (err, data) {...}` and if I upload JUST an image (no other content) it seems to save okay. Is that the proper way to do that? I mean I realize I could "insert" an object with my choice of fields, but I really want to use `req.body` to capture them all PLUS the file input.

Comment: Don't get your meaning. You think you want to store the whole content of req.body why? What do you think you are storing? Also your usage is wrong. `target_path` is just a String in a var. You need an object. Ignoring req.body for now, this would be a simple document `.insert({ "filename": target_path })`

Comment: It's difficult to explain why I need to store the whole content of `req.body`, but essentially it's because I can't tell what fields are going to need to be added. They get added and removed on the fly with jQuery (it's a super hack unfortunately...). And thanks for pointing out my stupidity of `target_path` being a string and not an object :)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do that but each to their own, but of course you can pass in only 1 object, so pick a property and add the filename to it. `req.body.myfilename = target_path;` Then you can just pass in `req.body` to insert.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! And I know, this is the first node.js app I've done so I'm learning a ton but just want to get this finished and then start over using Sails I think.