# Streaming files directly into GridFS with Node.js, Express.js and gridfs-stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am using latest version of express, mongodb, nodejs etc. I am not using body parsing middleware as I DONT want to store files on disk when I upload them. I just want to stream them directly into GridFs. I am using the gridfs-stream npm module. I know that ExpressJs uses formidable underneath. Remember - I dont want the files to hit the disk.

Here is my route handler where I just post one multipart form - the form contains one file only along with 1-3 optional fields.

Why oh Why is form.on('part',function(part)) - called multiple times for the same part for files say over 100kb and yet for smaller files - we just get one call??

What I am really trying to do is actually stream a file from an upload directly into GridFs and attach any form post fields in the same post to the GridFs metadata.

```
mymodule.prototype.save = function(req,res,next) {


if(req._body) {
    //return next();
}else if(contentType(req) !== 'multipart/form-data') {
    return next();
}

var gfs = Grid(req.ctx.app.database.connection.db, mongo); 

req.body  || (req.body = {});
req.files || (req.files = {});

var form = req.form,
    body      = req.body,
    files     = req.files,
    cb_called = false;

var parts = {};
var info = '';

var fileId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
var gfs_ws;

form.on('part', function(part) {
    if (part.filename) { ///// THIS IS CALLED MORE THAN ONCE for each part.filename???? on large files -- but why???
        sendPart(part);
    }
});

form.on('field', function(name, value) {
    if ( Array.isArray(body[name]) ) {
        body[name].push(value);
    }else if (body[name]) {
        body[name] = [body[name], value];
    }else{
        body[name] = value;
    }
});

form.on('error', function(err) {
    if (err && err.length > 1){
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.send({success: false, err: err});
    }
});

form.on('close', function() {
    try {
        //req.body = qs.parse(body); // if additional fields sent - for now we ignore them
    }
    catch (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.send({ success: true }); //, id: fileId.toString() });
});

form.parse(req);

function contentType(req) {
    return req.headers['content-type'] && req.headers['content-type'].split(';')[0];
}

function sendPart(part) {

    if (!gfs_ws) { // THIS IS MY ATTEMPT TO STREAM ALL PARTS OF THE SAME FILE TO THE SAME GRIDFS RECORD - but really we should only ever have called sendPart(part) once for each file
        var options = {
            _id: fileId, // a MongoDb ObjectId
            filename: part.filename, // a filename
            mode: 'w', // default value: w+, possible options: w, w+ or r, see [GridStore](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/gridstore.html)

            //any other options from the GridStore may be passed too, e.g.:
            //chunkSize: 1024, 
            content_type: part.headers['content-type'], //file.type , // For content_type to work properly, set "mode"-option to "w" too!
            //root: 'my_collection',
            metadata: {
                    recordId: req.params.recordid,
                    elementId: req.params.elementid
                }
        };
        gfs_ws = gfs.createWriteStream(options);
    }

    part.pipe(gfs_ws);

}
```

}

When I post small files (i.e. <100kb) form.on('part' ... gets called just once for each file part - and once for each field part. I only have only file in the post - so sendPart(part) only gets called one and the file gets put in GridFs and happy days.

However - with larger files i.e > 100kb - form.on('part' - gets called multiple times for the same file - i.e. part.filename is the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want the body parser set up as you likely have in order to do this. You actually want direct use of the `pipe` interface.

There are two things, first configure express to diable the `mutipart` function in the body parser. Described in this post:

[How to disable Express BodyParser for file uploads (Node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295554/how-to-disable-express-bodyparser-for-file-uploads-node-js)

Secondly use pipe to channel to [gridfs-stream](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream), as another component. This post gives an example usage:

[Storing data stream from POST request in GridFS, express, mongoDB, node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860005/storing-data-stream-from-post-request-in-gridfs-express-mongodb-node-js)

Comment: Hi Neil - thanks for the reply. I have things setup like this:
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart({defer: true})); 

I had previously come across the two links posted. Neither deal with the underlying question which is why does form.on('part fire multiple times for the same part? should I expect it to? If so how would I buffer the incoming data and later turn that buffer into a pipe?