# Insert an image in mongodb using GridFS

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, mongoose

i am trying to upload a image in mongoose collection using nodejs & express, first i tried in uploading in temporary folder it's works perfectly. but inserting in to mongoose collection using **GridFS** query is difficult to me, i familiar to creating schema and insert query. please guide me. 
here i giving my server side code for how i uploading file to temporary folder.

```
exports.uploadimg = function(req, res){
    console.log("c1",req.files);
    console.log("c2",req.files.uploaded_file.originalFilename);
    console.log("c3",req.files.uploaded_file.path);
    fs.readFile(req.files.uploaded_file.path, function (err, data){
        var dirname = "/home/Mel/www/2013/img-folder";
        var newPath = dirname + "/classes/" +   req.files.uploaded_file.originalFilename;
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if(err){
                res.json({'response':"Error"});
            }else {
                res.json({'response':"Saved"});
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout following link to find out solution of this question

[Storing data stream from POST request in GridFS, express, mongoDB, node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860005/storing-data-stream-from-post-request-in-gridfs-express-mongodb-node-js)

Thanks